# expressionegine matrix plugin check if field is empty

Tags: matrix, expressionengine

I have a matrix field with several columns. When user submits the form I want to display only column fields user entered.

How can I check if matrix field is empty?

Just to clarify I'm talking about expressionengine's Matrix extension.

For example this wont work for me since the row can be submitted empty:

```
{if "{exercise_set1:total_rows}" >= 1}
{exercise_set1:table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="format_head"}
{/if}
```

Comment: What version of EE are you running?

Comment: I'm curious about the use case. What's the difference to the user between "left the field empty" and "clicked in the field but left it empty"?

Answer (score 1):

To check if there are any rows filled use

```
   {if your_matrixfield:total_rows>0}
        {your_matrixfield}
            Do your thing
        {/your_matrixfield}
    {/if}
```

I had the problem that users could attachs files to an entry but when no files were attached do not generate the Gallery

Answer (score 0):

You just want to check to see if anything is set?

```
{matrix_tagpair}
   {if column_var}{column_var}{/if} 
   OR
   {if column_var != ""}{column_var}{/if}
{/matrix_tagpair}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this:
    {exercise_set1}
    {if exercise != ""}
    {exercise_set1:table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="format_head"}
    {/if}
    {/exercise_set1}

Comment: No - the table tag does not allow for that. However you could do something like: 

{exercise_set1:table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="format_head" search:exercise="key word"} 

Since we don't know what your variables contain data wise it will be hard say for sure what will work.

Be sure to read http://pixelandtonic.com/matrix/docs/templates